# meteor server load vs php/static site. Should I use a seperate static site for my main page?

Tags: meteor

I host a meteor webapp and realized that the server load is much higher than with my other websites (php). Meteor causes the same load with a few dozen concurrent users as php for several hundred.

Is this generally true for all meteor sites or is it probably more due to the more complex nature of an app?  Would it be better to host the main landing page with php or even static and only route the logged in users to the meteor instance?

Comment: try kadira debug to identify your fatty code  https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-debug

Comment: I second @BlueBells suggestion. Use Kadira to narrow down where your code is inefficient. Meteor uses websockets and persistent sessions which require more resources than a typical stateless server. That being said, it can be very easy to make a mistake in your Meteor code that would cause significant performance issues as usage scales. Kadira will help you identify these problems and resolve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the answer depends on what you're goals are. If you goal is

a) Serve static pages - PHP is quite good at this. Meteor is not rendered on the server without extensive configuration using community maintained packages.

b) Build an app with a lot of features quickly. This is where Meteor excels. Meteor is a platform that supports easily building apps that update in realtime, among other things that are difficult to build at the application level. These apps are passed as javascript bundles to the client (browser/phone/etc) that are then run in the client environment. In order to support the realtime features, the client must subscribe to datasets on the server, creating a lot of memory usage. Also, there is a persistent connection for each client over websockets.

You mentioned a landing page, so that sounds like a combination of both. Generally you want to have a "branding server" that solves goal a) and an app behind it on a different server, goal b). Different tools are better used for different jobs.

I expect that you probably like the power of Meteor though. If you want to invest the time, you can achieve goals a) and b) in the same app by learning about webpack and react, react-router, code splitting, multiple entry points, and server side rendering, and a server to serve all of it (or multiple servers, known as microservices), which would probably be node w/ express in order to get the benefits of "universal javascript" but could be anything theoretically.  This approach gets the best of both worlds. These tools allow the application to be broken into multiple js bundles so portions of the app can be served separately depending on the entry point(URL) (/, /members, /app, /landing-page).